Memberpress List of Users Under a Specific Membership
I am using memberpress on my wordpress site. I would like to have a list of each user who is a member of a specific membership so I can place them in specific areas on my site for the back end users.
So ideally it would be;
Membership Name
Subscriber A
Subscriber B
ect
To make it slighty more complex I want it to give me a custom field instead of their username
Is anyone able to help me with this please? I got some code from ChatGPT but it didnt do anything so probally better to start from scratch. I also contacted Memberpress and they advised they do not offer any solution to this.
Please note I do not know coding, I have very limited experience with it, but I am trying to learn!
I tried the code from chatGPT in hopes it might work, sadly it was just blank.
<?php
// Get all users with a specific MemberPress membership ID
$members = get_users(array(
    'meta_key' => 'mepr-active-memberships',
    'meta_value' => '123', // Replace '123' with the actual membership ID
));

foreach ($members as $user) {
    echo 'Username: ' . $user->user_login . '<br>';
    echo 'Email: ' . $user->user_email . '<br>';

    // Display custom field; change 'your_custom_field' to your field's key
    $custom_field_value = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'your_custom_field', true);
    echo 'Custom Field: ' . $custom_field_value . '<br><br>';
}
?>```


Obviously I filled in the membership ID & custom field sections acordingly, sadly just still a blank page where I added the shortcode via a PHP plug in.

